# How to change a content in a window in PySide?

Tags: python-2.7, pyside, menubar

I want to click on a menubar "Tools" menu to change my window content completely. How do I do this with PySide? Should I call QAction and set new widget as a central one with a parent of an old window? I'm beginner in python and english too. So far I've created only one-window application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would define each tool within its own subclass of a `QWidget`. Secondly, I would add an instance of each tool widget thus created to the layout of the central widget of the main window. Finally, I would add actions to the menuBar and connect them to methods to show and hide the tools as desired.

Below is an example to show how this can be done with 2 different tools:

```
from PySide import QtGui 
import sys

class myApplication(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myApplication, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('No Tool is Selected')

        #---- create instance of each tool widget ----

        self.tool1 = Tool1(self)
        self.tool2 = Tool2(self)

        #---- layout for central widget ----

        centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        centralLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        centralLayout.addWidget(self.tool1, 0, 0)
        centralLayout.addWidget(self.tool2, 1, 0)
        centralWidget.setLayout(centralLayout)

        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)  

        #---- set the menu bar ----

        contentMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu(("Tools"))
        contentMenu.addAction('show Tool 1', self.show_Tool1)
        contentMenu.addAction('show Tool 2', self.show_Tool2)
        contentMenu.addAction('show All', self.show_All)

    def show_Tool1(self):
        self.tool1.show()
        self.tool2.hide()
        self.setWindowTitle('Tool #1 is Selected')

    def show_Tool2(self):
        self.tool1.hide()
        self.tool2.show()
        self.setWindowTitle('Tool #2 is Selected')

    def show_All(self):
        self.tool1.show()
        self.tool2.show()
        self.setWindowTitle('All Tools are Selected')

class Tool1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Tool1, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Tool #1'))
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.hide()

class Tool2(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Tool2, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QtGui.QTextEdit('Tool #2'))
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.hide()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    instance = myApplication()  
    instance.show()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: This works great! One more question: how to make that every tool has its own window title. I have put 'self.setWindowTitle("title")' in my tool1 and tool2 class but it does not change when the tool is selected.

Comment: @HrvojeT What you did would have had an impact if your tools were shown in a standalone window.  In the example above, each tool is owned by the `myApplication` since they were added to its layout.  Therefore,  you need to change the window title of `myApplication` instead. This can be done within the methods called by the menuBar actions. I've updated the example to show you that.

Comment: @HrvojeT For the sake of the exercice, remove the `self` argument when creating the tools instance (e.g. `self.tool1 = Tool1()` and comment the lines where the tools are added to the `centralWidget` layout (e.g. `centralLayout.addWidget(self.tool1, 0, 0)`). Now the tools will show as standalone popup window when selected instead of being displayed within the main window of the application, each with its own independent window title.

Comment: Removing 'self' means it does not have a parent? Great, I learned a lot today

Comment: @HrvojeT Yes, this is correct, `Parent` will then be `None`. Passing `self` as a parent to the tool widget was not really necessary for the simple example above.